# Is it possible to integrate a Browser engine to a custom Browser interface?

Tags: dom, web, browser, webkit, servo

Recently I was reading an article about "**Browser Internals**" and suddenly this idea struck me.

> What if I create my own Browser?

So, I have two questions with me.

**Question 1:**

Is it possible to integrate an Open source Web Engine like "**Servo**" or "**WebKit**" to my custom Browser UI interface created using QtCreator or Visual Studio?

**Question 2:**

Is there any other components that needs to be inserted between the UI created using C++(QtCreator) and Servo or WebKit?

**Note:**
I am a complete beginner to this field and these questions were asked in a curiosity to learn internal stuff. Pardon if the Questions were not standard.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

Yes, it is possible. Browser engines have public APIs to provide a way to embed them. For example, the goal of this little project was to present how to build up your own UI interface (using Aura) and wire Chromium (browser engine) into that.

http://szeged.github.io/sprocket/

**Answer 2:**

If you prefer Qt technologies, then QtWebEngine will be the solution. The intent of this module is exactly what you have described: to embed Chromium engine into Qt applications with hiding its most painful parts and provide convenient API to customise your browser application.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-overview.html

And there are several others:

- QtWebKit: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebkit-index.html
- CEF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

You don't necessarily have to use extra layers between your application and a browser engine, but if you are a complete beginner, I would highly recommend that.